# What is the purpose of using the continue keyword

Tags: c#, continue

I just found a piece of code that looks like this;

```
for(;;)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        continue;
    }
    DoSomething();
}
```

What is the point of writing the code like this instead of just doing;

```
for(;;)
{
    if (!condition)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }             
}
```

Comment: That's a good question but really depends on the rest of the code. I would say you are right in this context but horses for courses

Comment: how do we know? ask the developer who wrote this

Comment: Have you ever read the documentation of `continue` statement and see how it's work?

Comment: In that situation, probably not much difference between the two. However, the conditions could be much more complex, and it is also cleaner to explicitly say "Move onto the next one if this happens".

Comment: The point is to reduce nesting/indentation. It makes your code neat and more readable. But in this particular case, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Selman22 Well, the question wasn't so much about this particualr instance. I just wanted to know the general rule for when to use what and used the code I found as an example.

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes, I understand how it works. But that wasn't my question

Answer (score 2):

In your particular case  - there is no difference at all because code block under condition is single method call.

But if code that runs if condition is not met is not a single call to `DoSomething();` but some large enough code block - then you will get slightly less nesting level (and slightly more readable code) when using syntax with `continue`.

Just consider:

```
for(;;)
{
    if (condition)
        continue;

    DoSomething();
    DoSomethingElse();
    DoAnything();
    ....
    DoAnythingElse();
}
```

and

```
for(;;)
{
    if (!condition)
    {
        DoSomething();
        DoSomethingElse();
        DoAnything();
        ....
        DoAnythingElse();
    }
}
```

Second sample looks less readable because of higher level of nesting/indentation.

Answer (score 2):

A possible benefit for readability becomes apparent when you add more such "breaking conditions":

```
for(;;)
{
    if (condition1)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (condition2)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (condition3)
    {
        continue;
    }
    DoSomething();
}
```

This tidily checks conditions that cause a skipping of the iteration, one by one.

Convert this into the alternative form:

```
for(;;)
{
    if (!condition1 && !condition2 && !condition3)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }             
}
```

Arguably, this is slightly less readable than the above. And it gets worse once there is actually some activity (e.g. a log output) before `continue`:

```
for(;;)
{
    if (condition1)
    {
        Log("condition1");
    }
    else
    {
        if (condition2)
        {
            Log("condition2");
        }
        else
        {
            if (condition3)
            {
                Log("condition3");
            }
            else
            {
                DoSomething();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

vs. with `continue`:

```
for(;;)
{
    if (condition1)
    {
        Log("condition1");
        continue;
    }
    if (condition2)
    {
        Log("condition2");
        continue;
    }
    if (condition3)
    {
        Log("condition3");
        continue;
    }
    DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Such use of a continue is more usually associated with code structured as:

```
for (; exitCondition;) {
  AlwaysDoDomething();
  if (condition) {
    continue;
  }
  SometimesDoSomething();
}
```

Ie. there are two blocks of code in the loop, and the condition controls the second block only. One might prefer

```
for (; exitCondition;) {
  AlwaysDoDomething();
  if (!condition) {
    SometimesDoSomething();
  }
}
```

But that makes assumptions that `condition` is sufficiently simple that the negation does not get lost in the expression (consider if `condition` is actually `expression1 || expression2 || expression3` where the sub-expressions themselves are non-trivial). And that `SometimesDoSomething` is short so it is clear the block controlled by the `if` is short.

What is clearest is both subjective *and* very much dependent on the specific circumstances.